# Subtraction of time formats in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to calculate the difference between hours. I tried using the formula mentioned above which uses the `ABS` function with the `TEXT` function and the `IF` function, but that didn't work. I also tried activating the '1904 date system' in the "options>advanced>while calculating this workbook" but that didn't work either.

Please provide a feasible solution, the values have been given as under:

cell D3: 09:36:00 pm (cell format: time)

cell D4: 12:51:00 am (cell format: time)

cell F4 contains the formula `=IF(D4="","",D4-D3)` with custom cell format as [h]:mm

The question was asked few days ago and was answered too... but the expected result from Excel is "3 hrs 15 mins" which is not showing; rather, it shows "########".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a link to the other question you are referencing ...

Comment: You are asking for assistance debugging a formula without telling us what the formula is.  I love a challenge, but still.....

Comment: It's kind of hard to know what needs fixing if you don't describe what result you're getting.

Comment: If a value is too wide to fit in a column, Excel displays "########".  Did you try widening the column?

Comment: I guess formatting the F4 with appropriate time format would solve this

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

1. Your number format is probably wrong. Set it to

   `h "hrs" m "mins"`
2. You are not specifying a date, so what you will get is -0.864583333, which is not a valid date value.

If you mean that the time in cell D4 is always later than the time in cell D3, then use

```
=IF(D4="","",IF(D3>D4,(1-D3) + D4,D4-D3))
```

Because times are scaled from 0 (12 Midnight) to 1 (11:59:59 PM is 0.999988).

Simply subtract the first value (D3) from 1 to get the time until midnight, then add the second value to add the remaining period after midnight.